# Does removing an element/child also remove componets created as part of the skin?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

General wisdom is when you remove a component from the stage you also need to manually remove all children so they are not floating in memory. Because they are just none visible since the parent container was removed.

Example of this would be a `Label` component inside of a `BorderContainer`. My understanding is you need to remove the `Label` first then the `BorderContainer`.

When you create a component such as `TitleWindow` the default skin for it adds a `closeButton` to the title bar / header.

I added an event listener to the close button. `TitleWindow.closeButton.addEventListener();` In the function called by the close button event i want to close/remove the window.

My question is this. Do i need to manually remove the `closeButton` as a child of the `TitleWindow`? Or do i just remove the listener then remove the `TitleWindow` from the stage and the components created by the skin are automatically removed / garbage collected?

Comment: As answers below explain removing a parent from the Display Tree for the generic case (not including skin information below) means all children are also no longer associated with the graph of all connected/used objects (it will be an orphaned graph) which means they are eligible for collection.  If any edge/reference (event listeners, or just plain object references) exist tying it to the graph of active objects then it won't be collected (as it may be accessed later which could result in a null object reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a component is removed from the stage, all of its children will automatically be removed and garbage collected as long as you've removed al event listeners. So you don't need to explicitly remove the children in order for them to be garbage collected.

**BUT** in your question you refer to skins. When skins are used their host component's `skinDestructionPolicy` property is always set to `never` (that is except for one mobile class; I forgot which one). This means that a skin and all of its children will simply stay in memory forever and never get garbage collected.

Now the not-so-happy part: it is not easy to override this default setting. Read this question and the answer I've written there to see how it can be done: [Spark SkinnableComponent skinDestructionPolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150934/spark-skinnablecomponent-skindestructionpolicy)

Note that in 99% of the cases this default behaviour is really not an issue. Of course I do not know your specific situation, so I can't comment any further on that.

Comment: I want to clarify, as you say skins are retained. Does that mean one copy of that skin is held and shared by all components using that skin? Or is there an instance of that skin for each component? If i add a panel, remove it, add another panel, does that mean i have two skins in memory? Or did the second panel use the skin already in memory from the first panel?

Comment: @phil_whiteboy There's no object pooling there: each skin is a new instance. Which does make sense: suppose you would alter one instance through CSS styling; if all skins were the same instance, that style would be applied to all components using that skin, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The conventional wisdom I learned is different than yours.  When you remove something from the stage; by definition all of it's children are no longer on the stage.  Assuming there are no lingering references to the main component or children, they should all be eligible for garbage collection.

Now, if you add an event listener to the close button of a TitleWindow; whether or not removing that TitleWindow from the stage will free up the component for Garbage Collection depends on who holds the listener.

If the TitleWindow holds the listener, then, since the TitleWindow is no longer on stage, both it and all it's children should be eligible for garbage collection.

IF the main application, or any component still on the stage, holds the event listener, then you'll have to remove that event listener before the component, or it's children, can be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Im not positive either, but from everything i have read if a listener is not removed manually it and the object it is attached to will stay in memory. EXCEPT when settings the weak to true, which is false by default.